# class toggling [jQuery/CSS]

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have built a simple `flexbox` layout and I am trying to get my navigation to toggle when it is *570px* or less to just have a button which says "*Navigation*" in it.

When that button is clicked, it should toggle the class of hidden from the li's, however, it doesnt want to do this and I am quite puzzled!

As you can see from my code, I am running a conditional statement on the `$(window).width()` to see if *it is <= 570* and then running an else statement for any sizes larger.

Can anyone figure this out because I can't for some reason.

Here is my CSS and jQuery.

CSS:

```
.hidden {
                display: none;
    }
    /*
    Nav Styles 
    */

    nav.nav-container {
                display: flex;
                width: 100vw;
                background: #333;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                padding: 20px;
    }

    nav.nav-container > .nav-img {
                justify-content: flex-start;
                margin: 0 5px;
    }

    nav.nav-container > ul.unstyled-list {
                list-style-type: none;
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                flex-grow: 200;
                justify-content: flex-end;
                max-height: 2000px;
    }

    nav.nav-container > ul.unstyled-list > a {
                text-decoration: none;
    }

    nav.nav-container > ul.unstyled-list > a > li.nav-item {
                color: #ffffff;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 20px;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 20px;
    }

    nav.nav-container > ul.unstyled-list > a > li.nav-item.active {
                background: #666;
                text-decoration: underline;
    }

    nav.nav-container > ul.unstyled-list > a > li.nav-item.active:hover {
                background: #999;
    }

    nav.nav-container > button.open-btn {
                border: 0;
                width: 100px;
                height: 40px;
                display: none;
                background: #000000;
                color: #ffffff;
                border: 1px solid #ffffff;
                outline: none;
    }
    /*
    Content Styles 
    */

    section.content {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                font-size: 20px;
    }

    section.content > div.left {
                flex-grow: 1;
                margin: 10px;
    }

    section.content > div.right {
                flex-grow: 1;
                margin: 10px;
    }

    .section-title {
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 250%;
    }
    /*
    Basic Responsive Styles 
    */

    @media (max-width: 570px) {
                /*
        Nav Responsive Styles 
    */

                nav.nav-container {
                            padding: 0;
                }
                nav.nav-container > ul.unstyled-list {
                            flex-direction: column;
                            max-height: 2000px;
                }
                nav.nav-container > ul.unstyled-list > li{
                }
                nav.nav-container > button.open-btn {
                            display: block;
                            margin: 15px;
                            flex-grow: 1;
                }
                /*
        Content Responsive Styles 
    */

                section.content {
                            flex-direction: column;
                }
    }
```

As you can see, it is basic flexbox styling plus a media query to change the flex-direction, etc and also to show the button for the nav toggling.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        if ($(window).width() <= 570) {
                    $('nav.nav-container > ul.unstyled-list > a > li').addClass("hidden");
                    $('nav.nav-container > .nav-img').addClass("hidden");
                    $('.open-btn').on('click', function() {
                                $('nav.nav-container > ul.unstyled-list > a > li.nav-item').toggleClass("hidden");
                    });
        } else {
                    if ($('nav.nav-container > ul.unstyled-list > a > li').hasClass('hidden')) {
                                $('nav.nav-container > ul.unstyled-list > a > li').removeClass('hidden');
                    }

                    if ($('nav.nav-container > .nav-img').hasClass("hidden")) {
                                $('nav.nav-container > .nav-img').removeClass("hidden");
                    }
        }
```

});

Oh and a link to my codepen also if you want to see the HTML, CSS and jQuery together too!

http://codepen.io/skulldev/pen/RPyEQa

Thanks in advance for any responses.

SD

Comment: You should put it in $(window).resize(function(){ ... }); to get called whenever the window size changes. But why aren't you just hiding the li with a media-query and css? Is there any special reason to use JS for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things were changed from the previous code and during the hybrid with shans' answer. Once I fixed the problems in shans' answer, I went forward to change to using the $(window).resize(function(){}); and with that plus the changes in variable scope, everything now works it seems!

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var nav_li = $('nav.nav-container > ul.unstyled-list > a > li');
    var width = window.innerWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
                if (width <= 570) {
                            nav_li.hide();
                            $('.nav-img').hide();
                            $('.open-btn').on('click', function() {
                                        nav_li.toggle();
                            });
                }

                if (width > 570) {
                            $('.nav-img').show();
                            nav_li.show();
                }
    });
```

You can see the full layout and code changes in my codepen: http://codepen.io/skulldev/pen/RPyEQa